redux toolkit + RTK query dynamic slice Injection using combineSlices
We are creating an application on the React + Redux Toolkit + RTK Query + Webpack Module Federation + Nx stack. The idea is to split a large application into modules, create a global store and fill it with reducers as modules are lazily loaded.
The problem is that when loading a module, the slice is not added to the rootReucer.
Folder structure:
apps/
|--shell/
|--moneyback/
libs/
|--store/
|--auth/
libs/store
This is a global store, it is assumed that when the application starts it will be empty.
export interface LazyLoadedSlices {}

export const rootReducer =
  combineSlices(staticSlice).withLazyLoadedSlices<LazyLoadedSlices>();

export const dynamicMiddleware = createDynamicMiddleware();

export const store = configureStore({
  devTools: process.env.ENV !== 'production',
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }).concat([
      dynamicMiddleware.middleware,
    ]),
});

libs/auth
import { rootReducer } from '@core-backoffice/store';


export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTokens: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<PayloadLogin>) => {
      const { token, refresh } = payload;
      state.token = token;
      state.refresh = refresh;
    },
    addUserData: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<IUser>) => {
      const { email, fullName, roles, userId, workspaces } = payload;
      state.email = email;
      state.fullName = fullName;
      state.roles = roles;
      state.userId = userId;
      state.workspaces = workspaces;
    },
    logout: () => initialState,
  },
  selectors: {
    selectToken: (state) => state.token,
    selectRefreshToken: (state) => state.refresh,
  },
});

declare module '@core-backoffice/store' {
  export interface LazyLoadedSlices extends WithSlice<typeof authSlice> {}
}

const injectedSlice = authSlice.injectInto(rootReducer);

export const { addTokens, logout, addUserData } = injectedSlice.actions;
export const { selectRefreshToken, selectToken } = injectedSlice.selectors;

apps/shell
useDispatch, useSelector and authApi are used in useAuth and useCheckAuth hooks
export function App() {
  useCheckAuth();

  const location = useLocation();
  const rootPath = useRootPath('/');

  const token = useAppSelector((store) => store.auth?.token);

  const { logout } = useAuth();

  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<NxWelcome title="shell" />} />
        <Route path="/moneyback/*" element={<MoneybackApp />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;

apps/moneyback/slice
The apps/moneyback/app.tsx also uses useDispatch, useSelector and servicesApi hooks and also uses useAuth and useCheckAuth
import { rootReducer } from '@core-backoffice/store';
import { createSlice, WithSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState: { services: string[] } = {
  services: [],
};

export const servicesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'servicesSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addService: (state) => {
      state.services = [String(Math.random())];
    },
  },
  selectors: {
    selectServices: (state) => state.services,
  },
});

declare module '@core-backoffice/store' {
  export interface LazyLoadedSlices extends WithSlice<typeof servicesSlice> {}
}

const injectedSlice = servicesSlice.injectInto(rootReducer);
export const { addService } = injectedSlice.actions;
export const { selectServices } = injectedSlice.selectors;

(image) authSlice in global store
After launching the application, authSlcie and authApi were added to the store.
(image) in the picture you can see that dispatch(addServices) is called, but there is no slice in the store 
All code was written according to the documentation redux toolkit code splitting
I expect that after switching to loclhost/moneyback, the moneyback module will be lazily loaded and servicesApi and servicesSlice will be added to the store. However, this does not happen.
UPD SOLUTION
Big thanks to @phry for solving the issue. Here's what we got in the end
libs/store
export interface LazyLoadedSlices {}

const keyReduxStore = Symbol.for('reduxStore') as unknown as number;
const keyRootReducer = Symbol.for('rootReducer') as unknown as number;
const keyDynamicMiddleware = Symbol.for(
  'dynamicMiddleware'
) as unknown as number;

const combineReducers = () => {
  return combineSlices({}).withLazyLoadedSlices<LazyLoadedSlices>();
};
window[keyRootReducer] = window[keyRootReducer] || combineReducers();
export const rootReducer = window[keyRootReducer] as unknown as ReturnType<
  typeof combineReducers
>;

window[keyDynamicMiddleware] =
  window[keyDynamicMiddleware] || createDynamicMiddleware();
export const dynamicMiddleware = window[
  keyDynamicMiddleware
] as unknown as DynamicMiddlewareInstance<any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>;

const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    devTools: process.env.ENV !== 'production',
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(dynamicMiddleware.middleware),
  });
};
window[keyReduxStore] = window[keyReduxStore] || setupStore();
export const store = window[keyReduxStore] as unknown as AppStore;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];


Is your moneyback module importing addService or selectServices? If you don't import one of those, it's not getting injected.

I was waiting for you) The problem is that the moneyback module uses both addService and selectServices, but there is no reducer in the store. Another point is that the injectInto method returns the reducer entity to me, but as I said, there is no reducer

update: Added a screenshot showing that the method is called, but the slice is not added to the store

This could happen if your bundler somehow bundles libs/store twice in different bundles.
If that happens, you could get around that by doing something like
window[Symbol.for("ReduxStore")] = window[Symbol.for("ReduxStore")] || configureStore(...)

export const store = window[Symbol.for("ReduxStore")]

in your libs/store

Thank you very much, it really worked. I had to declare rootReducer and dynamicMiddleware in the same way. I added the final file to the question body. If possible, please review the code. Maybe something can be changed.

Looks good to me :)
